# Filtering Date for current date -30 days fails

Tags: sql, oracle, date, filter

I am still learning SQL and have a sample database and am trying to show only orders in the past 30 days. Can someone tell me where my code is incorrect, and how to fix it?

```
SELECT c.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || c.LASTNAME as CUSTOMER, o.ORDERDATE
FROM CUSTOMER c 
WHERE o.orderdate >= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate()) 
and   o.orderdate <= getdate()
LEFT JOIN
     ORDERS o
     ON c.CUSTOMERID = o.CUSTOMERID
```

I apprecaite any assistnce.

On a side note I am looking for a SQL coach for Wensday and Thrusday of the coming week to help with these kind of questions. Willing to pay via PayPal and provide a WebEx for us to work. I wouldn't think more than a total of 4-5 hours oveall. If you care to help out a student and make some quick money please let me know your email address.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `SYSDATE` offset by the appropriate `INTERVAL`:

```
SELECT c.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || c.LASTNAME as CUSTOMER, o.ORDERDATE
FROM CUSTOMER c
LEFT JOIN ORDERS o
    ON c.CUSTOMERID = o.CUSTOMERID
WHERE o.orderdate >= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY AND o.orderdate <= SYSDATE
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly - Thank you!